# Displaying text directions with setPanel() in a new window

Tags: google-maps, window, panel

I'm trying to get the directionsPanel to show in a new window, but i can't seem to figure it out.

This is the function that sets the panel to a (hidden) div called 'directions-panel' in my HTML.

```
var directionsDisplay 
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {

var positie = new google.maps.LatLng(51.25584,5.68196);

directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 10,
center: positie,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl: false
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
}
```

The code works fine but I want it to open in a new window. Sort off like a pop-up I guess. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The basic workflow would be:

```
  //open a window
panel=window.open('about:blank','panel','width=200,height=300,scrollbars=yes');
  //create a document inside te window
panel.document.open();
panel.document.write('<body/>');
panel.document.close();
  //set the panel
directionsDisplay.setPanel(panel.document.body);
  //bring window into front
panel.focus();
```

Problems:

1. depending on your application the popup-blocker of the browser may block this popup
2. in IE it doesn't work at all, because it isn't allowed to move nodes between documents(there are methods to achieve it, but they are not implemented by the API as it seems)

I would suggest to use something like a draggable Lightbox or a (jQuery) dialog to show the panel

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I used a jQuery dialog box. 
Added:   

    $(function() {$( "#directions-panel").dialog({
                    minHeight:500,
      width: 800,
      height: 600, 
 }); to my executable function (that would go onSubmit), and it worked like a charm